# Checking if any of a set of radio buttons has been selected

Tags: php

I am trying to check whether any of the radio buttons on a web page have been selected when using PHP. I have searched around a lot and tried multiple things but nothing has seemed to work. I am trying to return a value of false to the variable $check so that later on after multiple of these checks I can stop the form from submitting.

HTML:

```
<form id="Quiz" method="post" action="markquiz.php" novalidate="novalidate">
    <fieldset>
<legend>What does the 'S' in OWASP stand for?</legend>
    <p><label for="Superman"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Superman" required="required"/>Superman</label>
    <label for="Segregation"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Segregation"/>Segregation</label>
    <label for="Security"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Security"/>Security</label>
    <label for="Simple"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Simple"/>Simple</label>
    </p> 
</fieldset>
    <p>
    <input id ="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
//Q1
        if (isset($_POST["Q1"])){
            $AnsQ1 = $_POST["Q1"];
            if ($AnsQ1 == "Security") {
                $Score = $Score + 1;
            }
        else {
            $check = false;
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if( isset($_POST['Q1']))` will not pass if `$_POST['Q1']` is null, so checking that inside the `isset` will never work.

Comment: Sorry copied the wrong part, what I had originally is now in the edited version of the post

Answer (score 0):

Try this and do add name="submit" in your button

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
                $AnsQ1 = $_POST["Q1"];
                if ($AnsQ1 != "") {
                    $Score = $Score + 1;
                }
            elseif($AnsQ=="") {
                $check = false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    $AnsQ1 = $_POST["Q1"];

    if ($AnsQ1 == "Security") {
        $Score = $Score + 1;    
    } else {
        $check = false;
    }

}
```